# Automatically install *.pkg via shell

Tags: macos, installer

I want to automate the installation process of an app that is provided in form of a pkg file

1. From other posts I gathered that the command

```
sudo installer -store -pkg "/path/to/file.pkg" -target /
```

would do the trick. Anyhow, this only results in an error like:

```
installer: Can't load package "/path/to/file.pkg": The file “Distribution” doesn’t exist.
```

Googling the error doesnt reveal anything much. Anyone here knows how to fix this?

2. And while we're at it: Any way how to pass the password that is being asked as an argument?

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: Yes, I am sure about that